# Any way to group items by property in UITableView in runtime?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a `UITableView` which I populate by a list of objects I'm getting from a Realm database. What I want to do is to create sections and group items in the list by a property value in runtime.

All of the examples of grouping items in `UITableView`  I see online are operating with it a prearranged dictionaries.

Is it possible to do?

Comment: You probably need to read Collection Types from Apple's documentation.  https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH8-ID107

Comment: I'd recommend Fetching all your data, then sort them afterwards, and finally load them into your tableView dataSource

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set up your table view data source any way you want. You could write code that decides on the fly which items belong in which sections, but I would advise against it.

I would suggest setting up a method that takes your list of Realm objects as input, and builds an array of sections containing sub-arrays of the rows. Then your cellForRowAtIndexPath method can simply index into your model data like normal.

Comment: why are you recommending against a code that decides a section for an item on the fly? This is exactly the behavior I want as I want to be able to toggle it.

Comment: Because you will have to sort your data into sections on each pass through `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. For anything but a very small dataset that will be too slow to be practical. Organize your data into an array of arrays when it changes or when the sort criteria changes.